# SPSS logistic regression. categorical --> dummies

Tags: regression, logistic, categorical-data

All our variables (question asked to students in our questionnaire) given by school are answered by:
1) very important
2) important
3) unimportant
4) vert unimportant

we want to use these variables as independent variables in a logistic regression (binary regression spss).

Do we need to change it into dummies where we chose a reference category (very important/very unimportant). Or can we just use it like this?

I would be very gradeful for some help!
Tom

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a copy of SPSS to hand, but from memory you can go to Analyse > Regression > Binary Logistic. In this dialogue box you can enter your independent variables, then press 'Categorical', which opens a new dialogue. At this point you can specify which SPSS should treat as categorical, and proceed from there.